# web.config file changings guide

Tags: asp.net, windows

Hi experts how are you all? i am student, and learning asp.net c# visual studio 2010 with using sql server 2005. I have developed a website which has database. I developed this website with self studies taking help from internet. the website is completed and working perfectly in my computer.

I have hosting server and domain name registered already.

the problem is when I upload my website it doesn't work there the following error displays:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error: 


Line 11:    <system.web>
Line 12:     <customErrors mode="Off" />
Line 13:   <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
Line 14:    </system.web>
Line 15: </configuration>

Source File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\urdureport.com\httpdocs\web.config    Line: 13 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5472; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5474
```

I don't know what should I do to get it work on hosting server please help me in this regard that what should I do with this. Thank you in advance

Comment: I've voted this question as off-topic because not only are you definitely not an administrator, but ignoring that, the question is lazy and badly researched.

Answer (score 4):

That error is *extremely* clear, and I question how much time you have spent thinking about it. The core message reads:

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'

So it's clearly a problem with this line in particular:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

The last line of the error message makes it very obvious there is a discrepancy here:

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5472; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5474

Fundemantlly, your AppPool is wrong a different .NET level than your development environment. You could try changing this, asking your provider to change this or you could try removing that line, changing `4.0` to `2.0` or perhaps simply Googling the problem.